# How to focus google maps on waypoint rather than 'Address' message?

Tags: html, iframe, maps

```
<iframe width="280" height="230" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0"
marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?
f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Milwaukee,+wi&amp;aq=&amp;
sll=42.970,-87.870&amp;sspn=0.004379,0.010568&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;
hnear=Milwaukee,+Milwaukee,+Wisconsin&amp;t=m&amp;z=12&amp;iwloc=A&amp;
output=embed"></iframe>
```

The above is the code I am using for a Google Map for Milwaukee, WI.  On the page, however, it's a relatively small map and it is centered on the 'Address' message rather than on the waypoint marker.  How can I fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: It's documentation should mention the zoom level...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It' pretty simple, the infowindow bubble depends on the `iwloc` parameter. Remove the Marker item from it, and it won't open it, by default.

```
<iframe width="280" height="230" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0"
marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?
f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Milwaukee,+wi&amp;aq=&amp;
sll=42.970,-87.870&amp;sspn=0.004379,0.010568&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;
hnear=Milwaukee,+Milwaukee,+Wisconsin&amp;t=m&amp;z=12&amp;iwloc=&amp;
output=embed"></iframe>
```

Notice `iwloc=&amp;` instead of `iwloc=A&amp;`.

[**Here is a Demo**](http://jsbin.com/asoqog/3/)